# Laravel 5 reset password for a logged in user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to use laravel's reset password functionality to reset password for a logged in user (I'll use that instead of enabling users to change their password).

My problem is, when I redirect to the password reset route (/password/email/) and the user is logged in, they will be automatically redirected to the home logged in screen.

My first try then.. was to implement a method at the User model called sendResetPasswordLink. But, as I looked more into the platform I would need to generate the token and add to the password_resets table..

I looked into DatabaseTokenRepository and PasswordResetServiceProvider classes, looking for a function I could call to generate the token, but there is no function I could call statically..

I'm really lost, can someone point me the way?

Comment: Shouldn't reset password only happen when the user didn't have his password?

Comment: Sometimes he will be logged in without a password (social login) to keep it simple I'm just centering all cases in the reset password functionality

Answer (score 2):

From the [`ResetsPasswords`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php) trait, the answer is:

```
Password::sendResetLink(['email' => Auth::user()->email], function (Illuminate\Mail\Message $message) {
    $message->subject('Your Password Reset Link');
});
```

You'll need to create your own route and controller method that allows this to be called for logged-in users.